# Pre-commit shows different result when running directly in command line vs running from make

Tags: python, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I have a Makefile that contains this:

```
SOURCE_DIR=./some_codebase/**/*

check-mypy:
    pre-commit run mypy --files $(SOURCE_DIR)
```

When I trigger `make check-mypy`, the result shows up as **Passed** (which is not correct), but when I run `pre-commit run mypy --files ./some_codebase/**/*` directly in the command line, the result shows up as **Failed** (which is correct). Another thing to point out is that I use `mypy` in this question only as an example, all other hooks have this issue as well (I also use ruff/black). **This issue also happens in my bitbucket pipeline.**

```
$ make check-mypy
pre-commit run mypy --files ./pyworker_v2/**/*
mypy.....................................................................Passed
```

```
$ pre-commit run mypy --files ./pyworker_v2/**/*
mypy.....................................................................Failed
- hook id: mypy
- exit code: 1
```

My `.pre-commit-config.yaml` is as below:

```yaml
minimum_pre_commit_version: 3.3.3

repos:
  - repo: local
    hooks:
      - id: mypy
        name: mypy
        entry: mypy --config-file ./pyproject.toml --enable-incomplete-feature=Unpack --install-types --non-interactive
        language: system
        types: [python]
```

I've tried running the command through a bash script and weirdly enough, the check shows up as **Passed** again (not correct), so this is not just an issue with the Makefile.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

pre-commit run mypy --files ./pyworker_v2/**/*
```

I also tried:

- Using absolute path (same issue).
- Test with an incorrect path to a nonexistent directory, which `pre-commit` correctly detects and fails.
- Do research on git hook caching/pre-commit caching, but nothing shows up yet.

Comment: off topic but your hand rolled mypy hook is a fork bomb

Comment: @anthonysottile hey, you're the author of pre-commit! I was expecting your answer or comment since I saw you in every question tagged with `pre-commit`. Thank you for the comment, but can you elaborate further, I dont think I understand...

Comment: you're running mypy N times in parallel and each process will typecheck your entire codebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a git issue, but a Make & shell one.

You're (presumably) using zsh as your interactive shell, which supports the `**` recursive wildcard as an extension to the original glob expansion.

Neither bash, for your bash script, nor GNU Make (which uses the same glob expansion as bash AFAIK) support this zsh extension.

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer. I tried to manually list some files in `some_codebase` to pass to pre-commit and pre-commit works correctly when using `make` now. Thank you!!!

Also yes I use zsh!

Comment: In Bash `shopt -s globstar` turns `**` on.

Comment: Good tip, I didn't know that. I don't suppose you know of an equivalent for GNU Make?

Comment: I'm adding this to the Makefile: `SHELL:=/bin/bash -O globstar`